# Check if array contains elements and if some elements are same then check for corresponding value in another array

Tags: javascript

```
var number = ['123', '123', '987', '567','675','675']
var city = ['Mumbai', 'Pune', 'Delhi', 'Bangalore','london','New York']
```

In the above array, I want to check if a number is the same for different cities. like 123, this number is the same for Mumbai and Pune then it should show an error. Javascript with max ES6 version is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The function will return an object whose key is a repeating item and the value is the indices of these repeats. Using them you can find and return city names in error provided that the number arrays in the first array correspond to the names of cities in the second

```
function checkReplicate (array) {
    return array.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {

        let hash = {},
            filtred = array.filter(v1 => v1 === cur);

         if (filtred.length > 1) {
             acc[cur] ? acc[cur].push(i) : acc[cur] = [i];

         }
          return acc;

    }, {});
}
```

If an empty object returns, no matches were found.

However, such a data structure is not optimal. Given your mention of ExtJS, it would be more convenient to describe your data using the [model](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.data.Model.html), add to the [store](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html) with [memory proxy](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.data.proxy.Memory.html)